# Questions webstore

Tags: google-drive-api, chrome-web-store

I need some light on the matter of  **Chrome Webstore registration**.

I'm still confused despite searching through the web: the "app" will be only private for the site (we're trying to develop a Elgg plugin for our website that will allow users to access their drives).

1) for testing, do I need to register it (I did a search but some say yes like in the Google Drive SDK documentation, some say no in the google-drive-sdk tags)?

2) when the plugin is finished, tested and ready to go live for our users, do I still need to register it and pay 5$?

Thanks you for the answer you can provide us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to register your app on the Chrome Web Store if you don't want to integrate with the Google Drive web UI: having the option to create a new file or open a file with your app directly from Google Drive.
Also, it might be easier for you not to create a Chrome Web Store listing while developing.

If you do need to integrate with the Google Drive web UI, but don't want your app to be public, you can publish your app to Trusted Testers only.